# why my content is not displaying properly on other pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

I have made this ecommerce site as my 1st react project.
I made some pages like Contact, Login etc. my footer and other components are rendering perfectly on home page but when I go to other pages the content gets shortened

providing the code sandbox link bellow
[sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-https-39efwy?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.footer-distributed { width: 100% }` to `.footer-distributed { width: 100vw }`